# Working example of Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, linear-algebra, pca

Are there any examples available that give a hands-on example of Principal Component Analysis on a dataset? I am reading articles discussing only theory and am really looking for something that will show me how to use PCA and then interpret the results and transform the original dataset into the new dataset. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know Python, here is a short hands-on example:

```
# Generate correlated data from uncorrelated data.
# Each column of X is a 3-dimensional feature vector.
Z = scipy.randn(3, 1000)
C = scipy.randn(3, 3)
X = scipy.dot(C, Z)

# Visualize the correlation among the features.
pylab.scatter(X[0,:], X[1,:])
pylab.scatter(X[0,:], X[2,:])
pylab.scatter(X[1,:], X[2,:])

# Perform PCA. It can be shown that the principal components of the 
# matrix X are equivalent to the left singular vectors of X, which are
# equivalent to the eigenvectors of X X^T (up to indeterminacy in sign).
U, S, Vh = scipy.linalg.svd(X)
W, Q = scipy.linalg.eig(scipy.dot(X, X.T))
print U
print Q

# Project the original features onto the eigenspace.
Y = scipy.dot(U.T, X)

# Visualize the absence of correlation among the projected features.
pylab.scatter(Y[0,:], Y[1,:])
pylab.scatter(Y[1,:], Y[2,:])
pylab.scatter(Y[0,:], Y[2,:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/svd/read-me.html SVD and LSA is very similar approach to PCA both are space reduction methods. The only difference in basis evaluation approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for available hands-on examples, [**here**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PrincipalComponents/) you have an interactive demo to play with.